# i3: emacs refuses to open in full screen after `fullscreen enable`

Tags: emacs, i3

After `for_window [class=".*"] fullscreen enable` has been put into `~/.config/i3/config`, and i3 reloaded, all programmes opened
open in full screen---except emacs!  The result is the same if `Emacs` is specified explicitly.  Why?
`mod+f` does bring emacs into fullscreen.

Comment: Does `emacs --fullscreen` work?

Comment: @Kusalananda, yes, if you mean mod+f.